# Raspbian: play video through HDMI from command-line

Tags: command-line, hdmi

I have a raspberry 2. I installed raspbian OS (only terminal) on it. I plugged in a HDMI cable, but it seems that it's not working. When I try to run video(or something) in command line nothing happens on TV.

I run video with VLC

```
vlc -f --play-and-exit /path/video.avi
```

So TV shows that HDMI isn't even connected. Am I missing drivers or something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to export your display, `export DISPLAY=:0.0`

Answer (score 0):

I've changed to player from VLC to OMX and it works fine now.